# How to use GitLab as local build and deploy tool?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I want to build and deploy my projects with GitLab's pipeline hosted locally and solely for build/deploy (sources hosted elsewhere). Everything GitLab related nicely stored within `my_gitlab` folder with:

```
my_gitlab
├── config
├── data
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── logs
```

in it and runs with single `docker-compose up -d` command. Runners, users, keys, etc. is all setup and persist between reboots. `my_gitlab` occupies `764 Kb` disk space and can be pushed to git repo to share local build/deploy functionality.

The only problem is that you cannot initiate pipeline by pointing to sources directory - you need to push sources to thus locally hosted GitLab with `.gitlab-ci.yml` in it. Each such push causes `my_gitlab` dir to grow up to `200 Mb`+ in size.

Is there a way to strip repositories data from GitLab or initiate pipeline without pushing code? Is it even somewhat OK usage of GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GitLabs Interface to start a new Pipeline without pushing any code.
On the left side in your project go to CI/CD -> Pipelines -> Run Pipeline and select your branch.